# Return specific nested node within XML from a SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

I need to return the value (Node) above the rows where 'Item' appears. This will be the column value for anything that appears as Key and Values. The other values (other nodes, not shown in this example) return back with the correct headings. Returning other nodes not under Item are fine.

I have created a CTE to extract the XML values from a column (`CustomFieldXML`) against the Client record that I am looking at. The way certain values are nested in the XML, my code works fine. The issue arises where the sub heading appears under 'Item'. How do I return each heading above the `<item>` node, but incorporate that into my CTE?

```sql
;WITH Clients_CTE_CastToXML AS 
(
    SELECT
    C.ID, 
    C.Name,
    C.Environment AS [Environment],
    C.[CustomFieldsXml] AS 'x'
    FROM Clients AS C WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE id=5806
),

XML_Data AS
(
    SELECT 
    [Id],
    [Name],
    x.y.value('local-name(..)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 'parentElementName',
    x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'attributeName',
    x.y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'attributeValue'
    FROM        Clients_CTE_CastToXML AS c
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('//*[text()], //@*') AS x(y)
)

SELECT 
    '' AS [Id],
    '' AS 'Source',
    '' AS [Name], 
    D.parentElementName,
    D.attributeName,
    D.attributeValue
    FROM XML_Data AS D
    OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Example of what is returned...I need to pull any level above the heading for `<item>` (so pull out the node that says `<DNA>` or `<RiskLevel>`). Not sure what the syntax should be for that node.

```xml
<values>
  <AuthorisingPartner>C</AuthorisingPartner>
  <DNA>
    <item>
      <Key>No</Key>
      <Value>No</Value>
    </item>
  </DNA>
  <RiskLevel>
    <item>
      <Key>Normal</Key>
      <Value>Normal</Value>
    </item>
  </RiskLevel>
</values>
```

[Image: See the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg22W.png)

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you want -- you can restrict the search for nodes with an appropriate XPath selector (`//node()[item]`) and you can fetch the element name of the node *above* yours by further extending the path (`local-name(../..)`).

Comment: Basically, the script above returns all the nodes I want dynamically, without listing specific nodes, except when it comes to those that have a sub node, where it appears under <item>. i need to know what the syntax should be to return the node above <item>. I don't want to use XPath to list out every possible field.When i pull out the value for <Key> and <Value>, i will not know it has come from <DNA> or <RiskLevel>. The current script just shows that it is coming from <item>.

Comment: Adding desired output based on input(s) would help. All you have now is your current attempt and what it produces.

Comment: You can see at the end, I've added an image - that's what the script outputs. Where it says Key in the attributeName column, it needs to say the name of the value above (DNA or RiskLevel). All the other column names come out correctly, except where it is looking at <item>. Does that make sense?

Comment: Where you mentioned this... fetch the element name of the node above yours by further extending the path (local-name(../..)). ...what would the exact syntax look like. I think that is my preferred option